# How do you unit test RazorViewEngineOptions in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core

In an extension method called from `ConfigureServices` I'm adding an instance of `EmbeddedFileProvider` to `RazorViewEngineOptions`. I'd like to test that it gets added but I can't find how to get the `RazorViewEngineOptions` instance.

This works when the application is run:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
                  .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddMyServices(Configuration);
}
```

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddMyServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => 
    {
        options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(MyClass).Assembly, "My.Namespace"));
    });

    return services;
}
```

But how do I test it? A `NullReferenceException` is thrown here:

```cs
[Fact]
public void MyTest()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    MyServicesBuilder.AddMyServices(services, new Mock<IConfiguration>().Object);
    var razorOptions = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions>>();

    Assert.Equal(1, razorOptions.Value.FileProviders.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(EmbeddedFileProvider)).Count());
}
```

I have tried adding `services.AddMvc()` or `services.AddSingleton<RazorViewEngineOptions>()`.

I've also tried calling `services.GetRequiredService<RazorViewEngineOptions>()` but that throws `System.InvalidOperationException : No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions'1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngineOptions`

I've also tried asking for `RazorViewEngineOptions` rather than `IOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions>`.

Comment: Anything added to the service collection after a provider has been built, wont be known to the provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything added to the service collection after the provider has already been built, wont be known to the provider.

Added everything needed to the service collection and only then build the provider to perform your assertions

For example

```
[Fact]
public void MyTest() {
    //Arrange
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddOptions();

    IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        // Call additional providers here as needed.
        //...
        .Build();

    //Act
    MyServicesBuilder.AddMyServices(services, config);
    //OR
    //services.AddMyServices(config);

    //Assert
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var razorOptions = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions>>();

    Assert.NotNull(razorOptions);
    Assert.Equal(1, razorOptions.Value.FileProviders.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(EmbeddedFileProvider)).Count());
}
```

Comment: @sussexrick glad to help.